# Получить разницу двух коллекций объектов

Tags: c#, vb.net

Имеем определение свойства

```
Private _join_fields As List(Of ExFieldJoin) = New List(Of ExFieldJoin)
```

Так же имеем два экземпляра этого свойства переданного в функцию как `ByVal` 
С разницей в том что в одной переменной, старый объект, а во второй, новый объект с новым объектом в коллекции.
Как сравнить эти объекты и получить несовпадающие элементы коллекции?

Comment: возможно нужен [Except](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb300779(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Grundy: Почему не как ответ?

Comment: @VladD, потому что занят пока :) можешь переделать :) к тому же подозреваю там еще и компаратор какой-нибудь нужен будет

Comment: @Grundy: Я вообще в отъезде :)

Comment: var nonintersect = list1.Except(list2).Union(list2.Except(list1));

Comment: Добавьте пример входных данных и ожидаемого результата

Answer (score 1):

**Ответ на заоловок:**

```
Var list1 = new List<string>();
//add some data to list1

Var list2 = new List<string>();
//add some data to list2

//разница двух коллекций объектов. Левый внешний
var leftOuterJoin = list1.Except(list2).ToList();

//разница двух коллекций объектов. Правый внешний
var rightOuterJoin = list2.Except(list1).ToList();
```

**Ответ на тело:**

Сначала лепим нужный джоин -- левый иль правый -- как тебе нужно.

Потом иннер джоин по нужному свойству твоего . В даном случае по .Owner групируем (одинаковые обьекты как ты пишешь).

Например так:

```
List<T> join = new List<T>();
innerJoin.AddRange(list1);
innerJoin.AddRange(list2);

var innerJoin  = join.GroupBy(pet => pet.id).ToList();
```

получишь сгрупированные итемы по параметру по которому возможно определить что это одинаковые обьекты.
Разберешься сам как лучше отталкиваясь от написанного тобою кода :)

Это и будут несовпадающие элементы.

А потом сам определяешь какой из них новее. Тебе виднее как. (например если есть параметр даты изменения -- по нему. И делаешь что там тебе нужно)